Grammar question of *au revoir*
I'm just learning French by myself and confused with a grammar problem of au revoir. Why does the infinitive of the verb revoir take the article le before it? If it is possible for the infinitive of verb to take an article, how to determine its gender?
I appreciate it if someone could answer this question.

Yes! Thank you very much!(⁠・⁠∀⁠・⁠)

Sometimes verbs can turn into nouns, like "manger" in Quebec can be a noun (here masculine), we can assume the same for voir et revoir. However, I do not see these words in the Robert & cOllin dictionnary. As for the gender, the origin of their determination is old and semi-mysterious.

The determination of the gender of a nominalised infinitive is not semi-mysterious: nominalised verbs in French are always masculine. I expect most serious dictionaries have a separate entry for the nominalised infinitives. It is the case with my paper editions of Le petit Robert and French-English Robert & Collins. On line TLF, Robert, etc.

Many thanks to you!(⁠≧⁠▽⁠≦⁠)

Thank you. I am learning something.
